# My Galaxy S4 shows a black screen with clock. What is this?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

I can't unlock or do anything with it. My Android version is 4.4.4 running CyanogenMod

Comment: Something similar has been happening to me actually, randomly my phone will have a screen similar to this one for a few seconds before going back to my normal screen. I've been trying to find out what it is but still can't come to a conclusion. Does any one have any ideas on what could be the cause? I haven't had my phone near any magnets also. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the S-View cover mode. That's a cover with a piece of glass in it. Are you holding magnets by your phone? If there is no way to get out of it, you should restart your phone, or you can hold a magnet near your phone like the red dot:

[image: s view cover photo]

Hope my answer helps!

Comment: This might be the case! It happened to me very randomly, and I usually put my phone in my pocket with lots of other stuffs. So are you saying that I could get out of this mode by again holding a piece of magnet by my phone?

Comment: I thinks so yes. There may be a Manet somewhere in your pocket. Hold the magnet something like the red dot in this photo: http://imgur.com/TgPJxqc

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!